# MVC Scaffolding - Quick and Easy way to implement Paging?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, paging, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC 4 application using MVC scaffolding. 
Currently it returns all rows in a single fetch and displays them in the grid. However, I want to implement paging within the same so that it doesn't create any problem when the data are in large volume.

Any idea of how can we implement paging quick and easy way in MVC 4?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This link](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) helped me to find out the proper way for paging, sorting and filtering.

Comment: It's best that you include the relevant parts of the link in your answer so that when the link dies the answer doesn't die with it.

Comment: @Shelby115, the link I have provided is from official site of Microsoft. They dont take off the page from their site at least until the product version becomes completely non-supported/ obsolete. Also, if the link survived for 5+ years (as I answered in Jun, 2013), then I believe the answer is useful..

Comment: ASP.NET Core 5 version: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/sort-filter-page?view=aspnetcore-5.0